# Как использовать ассоциированный массив в качестве аргумента внутри insert?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, stored-procedures

Я столкнулся с ситуацией, когда аргумент функции имеет правильный тип, но БД его не распознает.

Упрощенная модель:

```
-- Создам таблицу для экспериментов
create table my_table (a varchar2(1000));
/
-- Создам заголовок пакета
create or replace package my_pkg as
  type my_type is table of varchar2(1000) index by varchar2(1000);
  function my_func (p_input my_type) return varchar2;
  procedure my_proc;
end my_pkg;
/
-- Создам тело пакета
create or replace package body my_pkg as

  function my_func (p_input my_type) return varchar2 is
  begin
    if p_input is null
      then return null;
      else return p_input(p_input.first);
    end if;
  end;

  procedure my_proc is
    v_val my_type;
  begin
    v_val('Hello,') := ' world!';
    v_val('How') := ' do you do?';
    insert into my_table (a) values (my_func(v_val));
    --dbms_output.put_line(my_func(v_val));
    commit;
  end;

end my_pkg;
/
```

В данном коде компилятор выругается на использование `v_val` в строке:

```
insert into my_table (a) values (my_func('aga',v_val));
```

С текстом ошибки (с установкой курсора на `v_val`):

> Error: PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
> Line: 17 Text: insert
> into my_table (a) values (my_func(v_val));

При этом, если комментарий перевесить на `insert` и освободить от него строку:

```
dbms_output.put_line(my_func('aga',v_val));
```

никакой ошибки не произойдет. Хотя, очевидно, функция используется и ей передается тот же аргумент.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Было бы понятнее если бы текст ошибки был `Error: PLS-00231: function 'MY_FUNC' may not be used in SQL`, но это не наш случай

Comment: Конечно, в данной ситуации я просто сохранил значение функции в переменную и уже её использовал в SQL, но с познавательной точки зрения интересно в чем логика такой ошибки.

Comment: В sql-предложении, которым является INSERT, нельзя использовать переменную plsql типа, коей является v_val. переприсвойте результат вызова функции перемененной sql-типа (varchar2 в вашем случае) и используйте в insert её..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница двух строк, первая из которых - даст ошибку, вторая - работает:

```
insert into my_table (a) values (my_func(v_val));
dbms_output.put_line(my_func(v_val));
```

Первая будет послана SQL парсеру, а вторая - компилируется в PL/SQL.

Посылая предложение SQL парсеру, PL/SQL компилятор должен убедится, что во время выполненния он сможет передать все переменные связывания с типом данных, который, или известен в SQL контексте, или возможна неявная конвертация в SQL тип данных.

Тип данных - ассоциативная коллекция (*associative collection*), яркий пример PL/SQL типа данных, который не имеет в SQL контексте типа, в который он может быть конвертирован.

---

Из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1370235/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-oracle-%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8-ins#comment2432403_1370235):

> Было бы понятнее если бы текст ошибки был Error: PLS-00231: function 'MY_FUNC' may not be used in SQL, но это не наш случай

Эта ошибка возникнет, если функция не объявлена в спецификации пакета, то есть вообще неизвестна в SQL контексте.

---

Решением будет - не использовать параметры PL/SQL типа данных в функциях, которые могут быть вызваны в SQL контексте. Например:

```
create or replace package pack as
    function foo (key varchar2) return varchar2;
    procedure run;
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    type assarray is table of varchar2 (32) index by varchar2 (16);
    aa assarray := assarray ('key1'=>'val1','key2'=>'val2');

    function foo (key varchar2) return varchar2 is 
    begin 
        return (aa (key));
    end;
    procedure run is
        res varchar2 (32);
        key varchar2 (16) := 'key1';
    begin
        insert into t values (foo (key));
    end;
end;
/

exec pack.run

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```